# embed src error: putting titles in pre-coded message

Tags: html

I'm trying to add into pre-made code more.. information? to "hide" some information. (It's used for some kind of event.)
However, the type that worked for me once did not work twice :

```
<embed src="http://player.bgmstore.net/8Pifo" title="secret code here"      allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true" width="422" height="180" invokeurls="false" autostart="false" allownetworking="internal" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

This one was the one that worked for me; it showed the "secret code" successfully, and I was able to use it.

However, This one was different :

```
<embed src="http://player.bgmstore.net/kIQ40" title="another secret code here" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="422" height="180">
```

It played as what it was intended to (it played music), but it did not show the "secret code" that I wanted to use.

Are those two codes different? Is it the problem of pre-coded one or some kind of error on my side (inserting title)?

Thanks.

P. S. The site is actually Korean site; what it basically does is finding and sharing some musics with other users, which is where this code came from. Everything is same except for the title part.

P. P. S. Sorry in advance if this question is simple; I did not use html (or coding in first place) lots of times, nor did I use this code much.